# Case when doesn't accept BEGIN

Tags: sql, case, firebird, firebird-3.0

Case doesn't accept Begin

I need to update 2 separate fields in one case, something like below

```sql
UPDATE PYR SET
    MSR = 
      Case 
        When MSR = :WRKH then
        Begin
          MSR = NULL
          WRKDAY = WRKDAY -1
        end;
      end;
```

Comment: `UPDATE PYR SET MSR = NULL, WRKDAY = WRKDAY -1 WHERE MSR = :WRKH`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is invalid syntax, and will not work. You seem to think a [`CASE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-commons-conditional-case) is like an [`IF`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-psql-ifthen) in PSQL (Firebird's procedural language), but it is not. It is also not how the [`UPDATE`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-dml-update) syntax works. `CASE` is a conditional **value** expression, and it can only return one value.

The correct update statement would be putting the condition in the WHERE clause (as also suggested by [Iłya Bursov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2864275/i%C5%82ya-bursov) in the comments):

```sql
update PYR set MSR = NULL, WRKDAY = WRKDAY -1
where MSR = :WRKH
```

If this is part of a more complex statement that also updates other fields, you need to write the conditions per field:

```sql
update PYR set 
  MSR = case when MSR = :WRKH then null else MSR end, 
  WRKDAY = case when MSR = :WRKH then WRKDAY - 1 else WRKDAY end
```

or (using [`NULLIF`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-nullif) to simplify)

```sql
update PYR set 
  MSR = nullif(MSR, :WRKH), 
  WRKDAY = case when MSR = :WRKH then WRKDAY - 1 else WRKDAY end
```